Bubble sort on Doubly Linked List not working
I have been doing DSA lately on python, this time tried bubble-sort algorithm on a doubly linked list.
Unfortunately, the method is not giving proper result.
Please correct me, tell me where I am going wrong (I tried a lot but couldn't understand). Please explain and suggest the required changes.
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None


class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        self.count = 0

    def bubble_sort(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return f"Linked list is empty!"
        elif self.head.next is None:
            return self.head
        else:
            left = self.head
            right = self.head.next
            while True:
                flag = 'sorted'
                while True:
                    if right is None:
                        break
                    if left.value > right.value:
                        flag = 'unsorted'
                        if (left == self.head) and (right == self.tail): #only two nodes
                            self.tail = left
                            self.head = right
                        elif left == self.head:                    #edge case of left
                            self.head = right
                        elif right == self.tail:                   #edge case of right
                            self.tail = left
                        temp_right = right.next
                        temp_left = left.prev
                        left.next = temp_right
                        left.prev = right
                        right.next = left
                        right.prev = temp_left
                        right = left.next
                    else:
                        left = left.next
                        right = right.next
                left = self.head
                right = self.head.next
                if flag == 'sorted':
                    return self

Please help!

Note that the dsa tag is not what you think it is (read the description).

I have been doing DSA... -- Don't use abbreviations such as "DSA".  On  StackOverflow it means Digital Signature Algorithm.

When you swap two nodes somewhere in the middle of a doubly linked list, there are 4 nodes involved, and your code has correctly identified them.
Between those 4 nodes there are 6 links: between the first pair there are 2 links, between the middle pair there are 2 links, and between the right pair there are 2 links.
Your code only updates four links, so this cannot be correct. Namely, you have not updated the temp_left.next and temp_right.prev links.
To fix this, change the swapping code as follows:
                temp_right = right.next
                temp_left = left.prev
                left.next = temp_right
                left.prev = right
                right.next = left
                right.prev = temp_left
                ## === start of fix === insert these statements:
                if temp_right:
                    temp_right.prev = left
                if temp_left:
                    temp_left.next = right
                ## === end of fix ===
                right = left.next

Not your question, but it should be noted that bubble sort isn't really a good choice for sorting, and even less for sorting linked lists: the overhead for performing a swap is really too heavy. Merge sort would be a better choice.

Yeah thanks you so much man, I later realised and corrected myself.

Correct, bubble sort ain't good for LL. I was just trying to practise applying and expanding my ability of DSA (which is premature currently)

The fastest way to sort a LL is to copy it to an array, perform a reasonable sort on the array, and then copy the results back. . . .
